# SQL Server 2014: How to convert a VARCHAR column mixed with characters and numbers to corresponding numbers

Tags: sql-server

I have a column called `result` in SQL Server 2014 which has various kinds of lab test results. The values for `result` can be characters, numbers (integer or decimals or scientific notations) like this:

```
positive
negative
not detect
n/a
101
15.3
78.002
-12.1
3.49952E-10 
7.3E9
```

I want to only select those representing numbers, which are...

```
101
15.3
78.002
-12.1
3.49952E-10 
7.3E9
```

And, I want to convert them into a numeric column with the corresponding values.  I also want to get AVG, stdev, min, and max of them.

Can someone help me please?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you give us some background as to the source of this data?  Maybe you could scrub it before it hits SQL Server, thereby avoiding the need for some SQL olympics.

Comment: The data are in SQL server. Thank you for asking.

Comment: first of all, this is a terrible way of storing lab test results. I would recommend to split this into two columns, one status column used to encode all the non-numeric results, and one float column for the measurements. maybe a third for free text comments. then do a one-off update to convert all the numeric data, and in the future operate only on the float column.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ISNUMERIC` function and `CAST` it to number

```
DECLARE @SampleData AS TABLE (Value varchar(30))
INSERT INTO @SampleData
VALUES ('positive'),('negative'),('101'),('15.3'),
       ('78.002'),('-12.1'),('3.49952E-10'),('7.3E9')

SELECT CAST(sd.[Value]  AS float) AS Value
FROM @SampleData sd
WHERE isnumeric(sd.[Value]) = 1
```

Demo link: [Rextester](http://rextester.com/FOVIM82204)

Comment: To improve the quality of your Answer, please consider placing each value on a new line rather than on the same line as it is easier to read a large amount of data in columnar format rather than row, especially when that row requires scrolling to view the entire content.

Comment: Thank you very much! I need to include all the types of numbers though.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server **2012** and newer, you can also use the `TRY_CAST` function to try to convert a string to a numeric value - if it fails, it will not crash and burn, but instead just simply return `NULL`.

Based on that, you could use something like this:

```
-- define a CTE - an "inline" view which handles the conversion
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT NumValue = TRY_CAST(YourColumnName AS FLOAT) 
    FROM dbo.YourTable
)
-- select only those rows from the CTE that have a non-NULL "NumValue"
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE NumValue IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But I need to include all the types of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use pattern matching by using LIKE operator,

```
SELECT AVG(NumValue) AS Average
      ,STDEV(NumValue) AS StDev
      ,MIN(NumValue) AS Min
      ,MAX(NumValue) AS Max
FROM 
    (SELECT CONVERT(FLOAT,YourColumn) AS NumValue 
     FROM YourTable 
     WHERE YourColumn LIKE '%[0-9]%') x
```

This subquery will display any data that has number in it, and would return error if there is alphanumeric data other than exponential notation (i.e 3.49952E-10), in that case you could just specified the pattern after LIKE operator.

Comment: Thank you for help!

Comment: Will it work for decimals, such as 3.45 or negative numbers, such as -1.2? How to make it also work on all these kinds of numbers,

Comment: 3.49952E-10, -1.2, 3.45?

Comment: I just checked the data and found they are even messier than I thought. Some data values are like: <2.3, 3.55(UL), 123,456,789, TYPE 1A, LESS 12, .23, etc. Can SQL server handle the data like 123,456,789 or .23 in the correct way? I mean if it can treat 123,456,789 as 123456789, and treat .23 as 0.23 when use CONVERT(float, value) . Thanks a lot!

Comment: It would work for exponential notation (3.49952E-10),decimals (including .23), and negative numbers but wouldn't work for others such as <2.3, 3.55(UL), '123,456,789'. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

by using LIKE operator we can restrict string data

```
;WITH Cte (TextData)
AS
(
SELECT 'positive'   UNION ALL    
SELECT 'negative'   UNION ALL
SELECT 'not detect' UNION ALL
SELECT 'n/a'        UNION ALL
SELECT '101'        UNION ALL
SELECT '15.3'       UNION ALL
SELECT '78.002'     UNION ALL
SELECT '-12.1'      UNION ALL
SELECT '3.49952E-10'UNION ALL
SELECT '7.3E9'
)
SELECT *
FROM Cte
WHERE TextData LIKE '%[0-9]%'
```